# How often does Déjà Dup backup using "automatic backups" setting?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I have turned on "automatic backups" using Déjà Dup:

[image: Automatic backups control screenshot]

How often will Déjà Dup make a backup now? Is it once a day? The help documentation doesn't say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly, me, I missed this option under the "Schedule" tab:

[image: How often to backup setting screenshot]

You can set it to either daily or weekly.

If those two options are not what you want, you can set it to a specific number of days by modifying a Dconf setting. For example, to modify it to two weeks, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.DejaDup periodic-period 14
```

You can also edit this setting with dconf-editor, the setting is found in the tree path `/org/gnome/deja-dup`.

Comment: Yeah and now try to find out on what HOUR of the day it does that and you can answer another q on au :+

Comment: @Rinzwind: which one?

Comment: It will choose its own hour and time.  You can't control its scheduling finer than the day.